Can't get OneNote data using graph api from microsoft
I'm trying to get a specific page data using the graph API.
If I try to run through https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer I can put it to work, also if I use the token generated there it also works fine in script.
But when I try to generate the code in the script and run myself I get a 404 error.
Here is the script:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"

#get connection to the API working



app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id", client_credential=client_secret)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])


if "access_token" in result:
    print('Access Token: ', result["access_token"])

    import requests
    #response = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(result["access_token"])})
    response = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myuser/onenote/pages/page-id/content", headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+result["access_token"]})

Azure Permissions:

Error Screenshot:

Graph Explorer

Actually getting out of ideas on what I might be missing.
Already checked all the permissions over and over again.
Any suggestion would be much appreaciated.

Note that, Graph Explorer uses permissions of Delegated type that works based on signed-in user access.
But, your python code uses client credentials flow to get token that works only with permissions of Application type. I have one sample page with below content in my OneNote notebook:

When I ran the API call via Graph Explorer, it worked and retrieved content as below:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myuser/onenote/pages/page-id/content

Response:

But, when I do the same by running your python code granting permissions of Delegated type, I got 40004 error like this:

To resolve the error, make sure to grant Notes.Read.All Microsoft Graph permission of Application type with consent as below:

When I ran the code again after granting above permission, I got the response successfully with OneNote page content:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

client_id = "appID"
client_secret = "secret"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId", client_credential=client_secret)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])

if "access_token" in result:
    print('Access Token: ', result["access_token"])
    print()
   
import requests
#response = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(result["access_token"])})
response = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/onenote/pages/pageId/content", headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+result["access_token"]})

print(response.text)

Response:


Hi Sridevi,
I already have all the permissions in application too but the issue persists.
But thanks for your input!!

Could you include your complete error message and your API permissions image from Portal by editing your question?

Yes sure, just added a screenshot of both !

Have you granted admin consent to the added permissions? Kindly add graph explorer image too where you are getting results for same user

Yes, I granted admin permissions for the application permissions. Image added.

Okay. after I changed the response to json I see this error message:
code: 30121, message: The tenant does not have a valid Sharepoint license.
I have a personal Microsoft account with license, do I need to pay for Sharepoint too? For what I'm not using it, no sense.

If you are trying to access personal Microsoft account, you need to switch to delegated flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow to generate token by creating app registration with account type as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g., Skype, Xbox)"

So no change for a personal account to have the interactive because it would be a pain to do it every time the script runs.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
